# How can I get an NSImage from a CMSampleBuffer obtained from -captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler:?

Tags: image, avfoundation, capture

I have a Cocoa app that is intended to capture still images from a USB microscope and then do some post-processing on them before saving them to an image file. At the moment, I am stuck trying to get from the `CMSampleBufferRef` that's passed to my `completionHandler` block to an `NSImage` or some other representation I can manipulate and save using familiar Cocoa APIs.

I found the function `imageFromSampleBuffer()` in the AVFoundation docs, which purports to convert a `CMSampleBuffer` to a `UIImage` (sigh), and revised it appropriately to return an `NSImage`. But it does not work in this case, as the call to `CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer()` returns `nil`.

Here is a log showing the `CMSampleBuffer` passed to my completion block:

```
2012-01-21 19:38:36.293 LabCam[1402:cb0f] CMSampleBuffer 0x100335390 retainCount: 1 allocator: 0x7fff8c78620c
     invalid = NO
     dataReady = YES
     makeDataReadyCallback = 0x0
     makeDataReadyRefcon = 0x0
     buffer-level attachments:
          com.apple.cmio.buffer_attachment.discontinuity_flags(P) = 0
          com.apple.cmio.buffer_attachment.hosttime(P) = 79631546824089
          com.apple.cmio.buffer_attachment.sequence_number(P) = 42
     formatDescription = <CMVideoFormatDescription 0x100335220 [0x7fff782fff40]> {
     mediaType:'vide' 
     mediaSubType:'jpeg' 
     mediaSpecific: {
          codecType: 'jpeg'          dimensions: 640 x 480 
     } 
     extensions: {<CFBasicHash 0x100335160 [0x7fff782fff40]>{type = immutable dict, count = 5,
entries =>
     1 : <CFString 0x7fff773dff48 [0x7fff782fff40]>{contents = "Version"} = <CFNumber 0x183 [0x7fff782fff40]>{value = +1, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
     2 : <CFString 0x7fff773dff68 [0x7fff782fff40]>{contents = "RevisionLevel"} = <CFNumber 0x183 [0x7fff782fff40]>{value = +1, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
     3 : <CFString 0x7fff7781ab08 [0x7fff782fff40]>{contents = "CVFieldCount"} = <CFNumber 0x183 [0x7fff782fff40]>{value = +1, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
     4 : <CFString 0x7fff773dfdc8 [0x7fff782fff40]>{contents = "FormatName"} = <CFString 0x7fff76d35fb0 [0x7fff782fff40]>{contents = Photo - JPEG"}
     5 : <CFString 0x7fff773dff88 [0x7fff782fff40]>{contents = "Vendor"} = <CFString 0x7fff773dffa8 [0x7fff782fff40]>{contents = "appl"}
}
}
}
     sbufToTrackReadiness = 0x0
     numSamples = 1
     sampleTimingArray[1] = {
          {PTS = {2388943236/30000 = 79631.441, rounded}, DTS = {INVALID}, duration = {3698/30000 = 0.123}},
     }
     sampleSizeArray[1] = {
          sampleSize = 55911,
     }
     dataBuffer = 0x100335300
```

It clearly appears to contain JPEG data, but how do I get at it? (Preferably keeping the associated metadata along for the ride…)

Comment: Can you share how you "revised imageFromSampleBuffer()  appropriately to return an NSImage"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I eventually solved this with help from another code example. `CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer` only returns a valid result for the uncompressed, native image formats available from the camera. So to get my program to work, I had to configure the `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` instance to use `k32BGRAPixelFormat` instead of its default (JPEG) compressed format.

```
session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
imageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
// Configure imageOutput for BGRA pixel format [#2].
NSNumber * pixelFormat = [NSNumber numberWithInt:k32BGRAPixelFormat];
[imageOutput setOutputSettings:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:pixelFormat
                                                           forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey]];
[session addOutput:imageOutput];
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Would have take forever to have figured this out!